# Can I create nested collections in Jekyll?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to use Jekyll to create a manual that contains several chapters, each of which contains several sections, and store each section in a separate Markdown file. I want `index.md` to look something like this:

```
<ol>
{% for chapter in site.chapters %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{chapter.url}}">{{chapter.title}}</a>
    <ol>
    {% for section in chapter.sections %}
      <li><a href="{{section.url}}">{{section.title}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ol>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
<ol>
```

If each chapter is a Markdown file in `_chapters`, and I add the right lines to `_config.yml`, I can iterate over the chapters, pull out the title field from the YAML header, etc. Is there a way to nest this? I've tried creating sub-directories under `_chapters` with various names, but (a) Jekyll doesn't pick them up as sub-collections and (b) there's no obvious place to store chapter-level information (like the chapter's overall title).

(Note: I think I can do this by explicitly enumerating chapters and sections in a block of YAML in `_config.yml`, or by creating a separate YAML file in `_data`, but I don't want to have to worry about keeping that enumeration in sync with the actual chapters and sections: I'd like Jekyll to pick up changes automatically.)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So the best way I know how to do this is to invert your thinking.

You're not writing *chapters*, you're writing *sections* and organising them *into* chapters.

Assume you have a setup like this:

- _sections

  - section01.md
  - section02.md
  - section03.md
  - section04.md

But you want it output like this:

- _site

  - chapters

    - chapter1.html (contains `section01.md` followed by `section03.md`)
    - chapter2.html (contains `section02.md` followed by `section04.md`)

If that's the case, you can do so using collections. Set the `chapter` property in the frontmatter of `section01.md` and `section03.md` to `01` and the `chapter` property in the frontmatter of `section02.md` and `section04.md` to `02`.

The problem is generating the pages for the chapters. You *do* need to make a page for each chapter, but it's not bad if you use a layout.

Here's the layout I used (in `_layouts/chapter.html`):

```
---
layout: default
---

<h1>Chapter {{ page.chapter }}</h1>

{% for section in site.sections %}
{% if section.chapter == page.chapter %}
{{ section.output }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then in `_chapters`, I have `chapter01.md`, which looks like this:

```
---
chapter: 01
layout: chapter
---
```

Just copy that to `chapter02.md` and set the `chapter` property to `02`, and now you have Chapter 2.

The only other thing required to make this work is updating your config:

```
collections:
        sections:
                output: false
        chapters:
                output: true
```

When you run `jekyll build`, you'll now have `_site/chapters/chapter01.html` and `_site/chapters/chapter02.html`. As new sections get created, they'll be added to whatever chapter is in their frontmatter.

This is all really confusing, so I set up a sample at http://paddycarver.github.io/jekyll-nested-collections-example/ with source code at https://github.com/paddycarver/jekyll-nested-collections-example.

Comment: Thanks Paddy - it's kind of horrible, but it'll work.

Comment: My pleasure! Sorry it took so long. It can be made marginally better (auto-creating the chapter files) using a jekyll plugin, but that won't work on Github Pages.

Comment: I probably am stupid, but I cannot find the string "This is a link to Section 01" in the source code. What am I missing?

Comment: Check the gh-pages branch

Comment: Instead of the nesting the `if`, an alternative is to define a variable like `{{ assign page_sections = site.sections | where "chapter",page.chapter }}` then iterate over that.

Comment: I tried something like this but in my 'sections' (actually slideshow slides) any liquid things like "relative_url" were not converted. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be noted for `_collection` is the same as `_post`:

> The nested files are treated the same as the files in the root folder.

You could arrange the markdown files using `weight` as below:

```
_chapter
   chapter1.md <- put weight: 10
   chapter2.md <- put weight: 20
   _chapter/section1
      section11.md <- put weight: 11
      section12.md <- put weight: 12
   _chapter/section2
      section21.md <- put weight: 21
      section22.md <- put weight: 22
```

then sort to the index file by their `path` like this

```
<ol>
{% assign items = site.chapter | sort: 'weight' %}
{% for item in items %}
  {% if not item.path contains '/section' %}
  <li>
    <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a>
    <ol>
  {% else %}
      <li><a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.title}}</a></li>
  {% endif %}
    </ol>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
<ol>
```

output

```
<ol>
  <li>
    <a href="chapter1.html">chapter1</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="section11.html">section11</a></li>
      <li><a href="section12.html">section12</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="chapter2.html">chapter2</a>
    <ol>
      <li><a href="section21.html">section21</a></li>
      <li><a href="section22.html">section22</a></li>
    </ol>
  </li>
<ol>
```