# How can I organize notes by class on a Jekyll/github-pages hosted website?

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I'm interested in collecting some of my lecture notes and hosting them on my personal website to share with other students and for my own reference. Essentially, I would like the notes for each lecture to exist at `{me}.github.io/notes/{class}/lecture_{number}.html`

I started by creating a GitHub repository for each class, and setting up a corresponding project page. However, this places each class at the base of my website, e.g. `{me}.github.io/{class}/notes/`, and I'd prefer to have a single reference page that organizes my classes, as above.

I also tried using Jekyll collections to handle this, but it seems like you can't create nested collections. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277738/can-i-create-nested-collections-in-jekyll) related question for a pseudo-workaround, but it requires me to store all of my notes in a single directory, which I'm reluctant to do.

Is it possible to accomplish what I'm hoping for cleanly, or do I have to hard-code it all in or use the workaround above? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably achieve something like this with collections, but there is a much easier way.

First, you'll need to create a repository called 'notes', and turn on GitHub Pages for it (as you've already done). Add `baseurl: "/notes"` to `_config.yml`.

Your site will now be served at `{me}.github.io/notes/`.

Then, in that repository, create a folder for each class. And in each class folder, create a markdown file for each lecture. E.g. `lecture_1.md`.

Finally, turn off Jekyll's pretty permalinks by adding this to `_config.yml`:

`permalink: none`

That should give you the URL structure you're after. Your notes for lecture 1 would be at `{me}.github.io/notes/{class}/lecture_1.html`.