# Jekyll: render top level elements (only), of nested collection?

Tags: html, jekyll, liquid

Using Jekyll Liquid templates: how might I render items (in a collection) using a for loop, **but only output those elements at the top** of a collection hierarchy?

```
proj_folder
  - _items
    • item_1.md
    • item_2.md
    - subfolder_1
      • item_1-1.md
      • item_1-2.md
    - subfolder_2
      • item_2-1.md
      • item_2-2.md
```

OK, so if I do a standard for loop:

```
{% for item in site.items %}        
    <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I will get something like:

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 1-1
Item 1-2
Item 2-1
Item 2-2
```

**But I really want to stop at the top level.**  So I instead want only this (without the sub-folders):

```
Item 1
Item 2
```

I have seen posts where people [monkey with frontmatter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37770419/652626), explicitly tagging top-level items as "top" or some such.  This won't work for me; I need to do this in template logic only. Possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at the page.url to determine whether it is a subfolder or not. You could split it on a slash and check the length.

Something like this (not tested):

```
{% for item in site.items %}
    {% assign itemurl = item.url | split: '/' %}
    {% unless itemurl[1] %}
      <p>{{ item.name }}</p>
    {% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hey, this is smart.  Thanks.