# Build Jekyll pages recursively from directory tree

Tags: jekyll

I love Markdown + MathJax for note taking, and I've found the simplest way to do this is to use a small, local Jekyll server that I can backup using Git. It's simple, clean, private, and redundant; each document is a single human-readable file *before* processing, meaning I hope that in 20 years the notes aren't worthless.

My only problem is that I wish I could have a directory with subdirectories of Markdown files and to have Jekyll build everything recursively. For example, imagine I had something like this:

```
...
- research
    - foo
       - derivations
           - derivation1.md
           - derivation2.md
           ...
       - meetings
           - 20190912_meeting1.md
           - 20190912_meeting2.md
           ...
    - bar
       - derivations
       - meetings
- personal
- courses
    - qux
    - baz
...
```

I would love to automatically render and a locally host a web server in which each directory is an index page, and each `.md` file is a document.

Is it possible to do this relatively easily in Jekyll? I've seen some stuff using [nested collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37277738/can-i-create-nested-collections-in-jekyll), but it's pretty messy and manual.

Comment: Did you ever get this solved?

Comment: @BenWinding, sadly no. Currently, I just use collections for depth-1 nesting.